# Element is not clickable at point error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After running my Selenium tests on Chrome browser while clicking on one element, I get following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (30, 22). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope dialogs-default in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="dialogs-default" size="md" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.101)
```

I'm using Chrome browser version `41.0.2272.101` and Chrome driver version `ChromeDriver 2.15.322448`

I search over internet and tried following -

**1**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(designerViewButton));
```

**2**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver.findElement(designerViewButton));
```

But none of them worked. Do I need to use chromedriver version which is lesser that the one I'm using it? If that is the case, where can I get previous chromedriver versions?

Comment: CAn you please share the link sothat we can investigate

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 variants.

1) there is really another modal view with is higher by z-index then your button and you are clicking the wrong one

2) you are trying to run it headless or/and on the virtual machine where you have not set the resolution